# Grouping items with most optimized value

Tags: mathematical-statistics, computational-statistics

I am looking to group items with different value and get the most optimized combination closest to a certain value. For example I have items such as the ones shown below, and I am looking to group them so that the total value is as close to "50" as possible (50 or above). What would a recommended algorithm i could use to find the optimized grouping?

```
 Item  Value
 -----------
 ItemA  10
 ItemA  10
 ItemA  10
 ItemB  12
 ItemB  12
 ItemC  5
 ItemC  5
 ItemD  8
 ItemE  25
 ItemE  25
 ItemE  25
```

For example if i was to do this by hand some combinations would be

### Group into 50s

```
Group 1) 25 + 25 = 50
Group 2) 25 + 12 + 12 + 5 = 54
Group 3) 10 + 10 + 10 + 8 + 5 = 43 (all is remaining)
```

So i will have 3 groups with one of them less than 50 (43 in this case)

or

```
Group 1) 25 + 10 + 10 + 5 = 50
Group 2) 25 + 10 + 12 + 5 = 52
Group 3) 25 + 12 + 8 = 45 (all is remaining)
```

In this case which is better than the first since i have two groups closer to 50. 50 and 52

But are these the the most optimized groupings? I am not sure, I was looking to see if there is some algorithm i can use to maybe calculate the most optimized groups

Comment: The total value of all your items is fixed. Do you mean that you're allocating every item to a group and the total value of every group must be close to 50? (If so, how do you decide whether 50,60 is better than 55,55?) Or do you mean that you're trying to choose one subset with a total close to 50? (This is basically the Knapsack Problem, for which algorithms exist, although being able to go over will change that a little.) Either way, this isn't really a stats question, and might be better asked on a different site.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was looking at the knapsack problem, but this is slightly different. I want to group my items into "n" different groups so that i can maximize my groups with values closest to >= 50. I have added examples to by question to explain what i am looking for in more detail

Answer (score 1):

The original question was not specific as to whether unique sequences, or all combinations of that same sequence are to be counted. It specified closest to 50 and not greater than or equal to 50. It did not specify without replacement, but just specified combinations. Moreover, the new problem does not specify what an optimum answer is, so the question is likely to change once again. Still ambiguous in a more general case would be, for example, whether or not four sequences that fit the criteria with an error would be better than three sequences that fit the criteria exactly. Whether or not that applies to the limited problem here is relevant to the code one would write to do that automatically. Why are we solving this newer problem? With many more numbers and without replacement this new question becomes intractable due to the large number of solution paths to be attempted. With more exact criteria, currently unspecified, it then becomes some variation of the [traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). That I do not know which variation of the traveling salesman problem this is, is due to, for example, whether symmetric solutions are counted separately, whether the number of sequences is important or not, whether total error summed from those sequences is more relevant or exhausting the greatest number of entries in the sequence provided, prohibits furnishing any unique answer at this time. Some observations are common to all possibilities, the ItemA column is not contributory, all one need do is test the objects in the second column.

For the original question which was with replacement, and a sum test of closest to 50, since there are multiple solutions that are exactly 50, then no least distance formula (still unspecified) is needed, and one then applies a sum test to each sequence, for which we will run through all of the possibilities.

There are many ways to solve the original problem. One is by hand.

That is, we count possabilities

```
5
8
10
12
25
5,5
5,8 (=8,5)
5,10 (=10,5)
5,12 (=12,5)
5,25 (=25,5)
8,10 (=10,8)
8,12 (=12,8)
8,25 (=25,8)
10,10
10,12 (=12,10)
10,25 (=25,10)
12,12
12,25 (=25,12)
25,25
5,5,8 (=5,8,5=8,5,5)
5,5,10 (=5,10,5=10,5,5)
 .
 .
```

And so forth, granted, it is a bit tedious to do by hand. Organizing that into a coherent combination pattern is not difficult, and, all I am doing here is showing how to "finger" count combinations, i.e., the brute force solution.

Now if we want to make our counting more efficient, and our objective is to sum to 50, we can start counting at a minimum of two combined objects and a maximum of 6 combined objects. This is because only the (25,25) two item combinations make 50 and the last combination of the objects that makes 50 is six items (5,5,8,10,10,12).

Now the simplest way of doing this is to write a program, and here is one in Mathematica.

(*Code*)

```
X={5,5,8,10,10,10,12,12,25,25,25};
i=Length[Subsets[X,{2,6}]];Print["Number of combinations is ",i]
Y=Subsets[X,{2,6}];
j={};
For[k=1,k<i+1,k++,j=AppendTo[j,Length[Y[[k]]]]];
Print["Combinations totaling 50"]
Num50Comb=0;
For[ii=1,ii<i+1,ii++,Ans=Sum[Y[[ii]][[ind]],{ind,1,j[[ii]]}];If[Ans==50,Print[Y[[ii]]];Num50Comb=1+Num50Comb]]
Print["Number of combinations having sum = 50 is ",Num50Comb]
```

(*Output*)

```
Number of combinations is 1474
Combinations totalling 50
{25,25}
{25,25}
{25,25}
{5,8,12,25}
{5,8,12,25}
{5,8,12,25}
{5,8,12,25}
{5,8,12,25}
{5,8,12,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{5,8,12,25}
{5,8,12,25}
{5,8,12,25}
{5,8,12,25}
{5,8,12,25}
{5,8,12,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{5,10,10,25}
{8,10,10,10,12}
{8,10,10,10,12}
{5,5,8,10,10,12}
{5,5,8,10,10,12}
{5,5,8,10,10,12}
{5,5,8,10,10,12}
{5,5,8,10,10,12}
{5,5,8,10,10,12}
Number of combinations having sum = 50 is 41
```

From these 41 combinations, we can see that only five combinations are unique.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have added some examples of groupings n the question. I understand the logic you are using to get the combinations. One point i missed explaining was once a number is used up the next group can use only the remaining numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification of the problem. By my understanding, your objectives are:

1. Maximise the number of groups that have sum >= 50.
2. Minimise the sum of the "excess" for these groups.

This isn't exactly the knapsack problem but it's a similar problem. I suspect it's NP-hard, which means that barring a major breakthrough the time to find the best solution will increase very rapidly as the problem size increases. For small problems you can use an exhaustive search as shown in Carl's answer above; for larger problems the run-time will quickly become prohibitive. (I'm not certain I've understood the exact requirements for your problem, but most of my comments here should hold anyway.)

However, this sort of problem is very important in operations research, so there are a lot of highly-engineered algorithms that will find optimal solutions to small problems and pretty-good solutions to larger problems. If you want to roll your own, google "MIP optimisation algorithms" and start reading from there. Otherwise, I'd recommend downloading a demo of an optimisation platform like AMPL and doing a tutorial so you can take advantage of algorithms that have already been coded by others.

I coded up my understanding of your problem in AMPL:

```
set Items;
param NumAvailable{Items};
param Size{Items};
param MaxGroups := sum{i in Items} NumAvailable[i];
# maximum possible number of groups we could make
set Groups := 1..MaxGroups ordered;
param TargetSize;
# preferred size for each group
param BigNumber := sum{i in Items} NumAvailable[i]*Size[i];
# Primary decision variables: no. of each item type per group
var Allocations{Groups,Items} integer >= 0;
# require that all items are allocated
subject to AllocateAll{i in Items}:
NumAvailable[i] = sum{g in Groups} (Allocations[g,i]);
var SumByGroup{Groups};
subject to DefineSums{g in Groups}: SumByGroup[g] = 
sum{i in Items} Allocations[g,i]*Size[i];
# symmetry-breaking constraint: require that 
# groups are ordered largest to smallest
subject to OrderSizes{g in Groups: ord(g) > 1}: 
SumByGroup[g]<=SumByGroup[g-1];
var IsGroupAtTarget{Groups} binary;
# Enforce definition of that variable:
subject to DefineTargetFlag{g in Groups}:
IsGroupAtTarget[g]<=SumByGroup[g]/TargetSize;
# If a group is smaller than the target, all subsequent
# are empty (i.e. only allow one group < target)
subject to OnlyOneSmallGroup{g in Groups: ord(g) > 1}:
SumByGroup[g]<=BigNumber*IsGroupAtTarget[g-1];
var Excess{Groups} >= 0;
subject to DefineExcess{g in Groups}:
Excess[g]
>=
SumByGroup[g]-TargetSize+BigNumber*(IsGroupAtTarget[g]-1);
maximize ObjectiveFunction: sum{g in Groups} 
(BigNumber*IsGroupAtTarget[g]-Excess[g]);

param: Items: NumAvailable Size :=
ItemA 3 10
ItemB 2 12
ItemC 2 5
ItemD 1 8
ItemE 3 25
;
param TargetSize := 50;
```

With the Gurobi solver, this runs pretty much instantly. The optimal solution is:

```
Allocations [*,*]
:  ItemA ItemB ItemC ItemD ItemE    :=
1     2     1     2     1     0
2     0     0     0     0     2
3     1     1     0     0     1
4     0     0     0     0     0
5     0     0     0     0     0
6     0     0     0     0     0
7     0     0     0     0     0
8     0     0     0     0     0
9     0     0     0     0     0
10    0     0     0     0     0
11    0     0     0     0     0
;
```

i.e. group 1 has two each of ItemA and ItemC, one each of ItemB and ItemD (sum exactly 50); group 2 has two of Item E (sum exactly 50); group 3 has one each of A, B, and E (sum 47). Obviously you can't do better than this, with this particular case.

If I try a bigger problem, with 5x as many items of each kind, it still takes < 1 second to find an optimal solution: one group of 51, thirteen of 50, and one of 34. I suspect exhaustively searching all possible combinations would take rather longer!

As I commented above, this is much more of a maths or programming question than stats per se.